# Issue with HSQL in memory database, LockAcquisitionException

Tags: locking, hsqldb

HSQL in memory database is giving CannotAcquireLockException when using multiple times in test cases.

We are using:
jdbc:hsqldb:mem:batchsqldb;sql.syntax_pgs=true

this is giving CannotAcquireLockException which is intermittent. It comes half of the time. I have also tried hsqldb.lock_file=false; in connection url but did not work

Comment: This exception is never thrown with an in-memory database. The database is a file database.  The URL you report is correct but check the spelling of the actual database URL in your app.

Comment: the url is correct because it does work ... only in multithreaded case it is causing the problem .... and this is memory based DB... not a file based

Comment: Can you add the stack trace for the exception.